# change cell format to general or text?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, cell-formatting

we have sort of data in excel like this ---> **34:5:20**
excel likes to consider it as time or date.
here is the problem because I know it's **not a date** and what ever action I want to do with it again
excel thinks it's a date/time value .
**how can I stop this behavior ?**
(each of the ':' delimited values has a special meaning to me but not date/time)
thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried by formatting the cells to `Text`?

Comment: yes I did and it changes the value to some thing even more inappropriate .like this ---> 1.332244334

Comment: You need to set the cell format to text *before* populating the values

Comment: Might not be the best option, but putting ' at the start of the string is one way. `'34:5:20`

Comment: dear @Tim , I'm not the maker of this file you know? I know your right in case I want to start a new file from the beginning .

Comment: putting ' at the start of the string totally changes the value . -----------> 01/01/1900  10:04:30 ق.ظ'

Comment: Where do you get the file from?  Is it provided as an Excel file, or in some other format (csv, txt, ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution finally .

1. copy column to notepad.
2. select another column
3. change it's format cell to text.
4. now paste from notepad.
   now my data is considered as text and I can separate the values using "column to text" from DATA tab.
   thank you all for your valuable time.

Comment: this will work, but its not dynamic, you have to do this every time the data is updated/appended

Comment: You can also use the data / text to columns wizard.

Answer (score 1):

There is one option though, you can use the formula below, to convert the dates back to your format

```
=CONCAT(" ",TEXT(A2,"[h]:mm:ss"))
```

I am adding a *space* using *concat* function just so that if you ever decide to convert all to value, it will not return back to dates

Comment: The value is changed to *Date* at the time of entry. This answer changes it back. I have upvoted it although the applied format should probably be "[h]:m:s". However, the formula can be used without change in a context like `=MID(TEXT(A2,"[h]:mm:ss"),FIND(":",TEXT(A2,"[h]:mm:ss"))+1,2)` to extract the middle value as a number.

Comment: hi .there is a little problem with "Text" function you mentioned and that is :for numbers larger than 24 it automatically converts to 24 system .For example 32:4:45 is meant to be 8:4:45 .text()  works properly but again excel changes the format of cell .

Comment: to stop it from converting i have used [h] and not hh, it works perfectly in my system and i tried with numbers larger than 24 also